# framework 'shared.framework' is missing one or more architectures required by this target: arm64. Xcode 12.0 kotlin 1.4.10

Tags: android, ios, kotlin-multiplatform

I created a shared library for both iOS and Android using Kotlin Multiplatform and everything was working correctly until I not updated the Xcode to 12.0

As I updated Xcode to 12.0 the framework stopped working for real device (iphone) but working on simulator

my Gradle

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
    id("kotlin-android-extensions")
}
group = "com.example.multiplatform_android_ios"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
kotlin {
    android()
    ios {
        binaries {
            framework {
                baseName = "shared"
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0")
            }
        }
        val androidTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
                implementation("junit:junit:4.12")
            }
        }
        val iosMain by getting
        val iosTest by getting
    }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion(29)
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(24)
        targetSdkVersion(29)
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
val packForXcode by tasks.creating(Sync::class) {
    group = "build"
    val mode = System.getenv("CONFIGURATION") ?: "DEBUG"
    val sdkName = System.getenv("SDK_NAME") ?: "iphonesimulator"
    val targetName = "ios" + if (sdkName.startsWith("iphoneos")) "Arm64" else "X64"
    val framework = kotlin.targets.getByName<KotlinNativeTarget>(targetName).binaries.getFramework(mode)
    inputs.property("mode", mode)
    dependsOn(framework.linkTask)
    val targetDir = File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")
    from({ framework.outputDirectory })
    into(targetDir)
}
tasks.getByName("build").dependsOn(packForXcode)
```

Xcode 12.0
Android Studio 4.1 RC 3
Kotlin 1.4.10

com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0-rc03

Comment: Same here. In my case real device is not working either with the following error: Building for iOS, but the linked and embedded framework 'shared.framework' was build for iOS simulator.

Comment: I've just created a new project following this documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/getting-started.html and same error is happening (working on simulator but not on real device).

Comment: I think this is the same problem as one reported to Kotlin issue tracker a few days ago. Please take a look at it [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-41854)

Comment: @pauminku check answer

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev yes I know that kotlin issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also got the same problem, and resolved by following these steps:

- Close Android Studio
- Delete build folder inside shared module
- Now open iOS App in Xcode and plug in your device
- Make sure you have run this script inside build phase of Xcode project

```
cd "$SRCROOT/.."
./gradlew :shared:packForXCode -PXCODE_CONFIGURATION=${CONFIGURATION}
```

- Now build project and it will be successful

Comment: I tried to copy/paste this code into the run script section of the build phases and got a script error.  Is the command exactly like you showed above or do I need to substitute something from my project structure?

Answer (score 1):

According to [KT-41854](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-41854), this problem should be fixed in KMM plugin version 0.1.3, available for the Android Studio 4.1 & 4.2. Please check if it is, and comment at the issue tracker if something is still wrong.

Comment: no, I am still getting the same error by using Kmm plugin 0.1.3

Comment: Then maybe it worth a mention on YouTrack. I also found [this report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-42407), where the author says the old project kept failing, while the newly generated works fine. Are you still trying with the old one? Please try re-creating a project before reporting.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Open iosApp.xcodeproj with Xcode. Choose tab "Build Settings". Choose subtab "All". Go the section "Architectures". Create item "Excluded Architectures" if not exist. Create entry under Debug "Any iOS Simulator SDK". As value entry "i386". If you need do it in the same manner for Release. Now, you can try to compile with Android Studio without errors. For non intel processor you need to add arm64 to value items.
[image: Xcode project settings]

Comment: so for you above answers not working? or you are trying to add more info to already available answers

Comment: the issue is already present after deleting build folder and with newest KMM plugin. This is the only solution worked for me.

Comment: ok, its good to heard that your problem solved by this